# onClick button function for a "selecting all" toggle on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox, toggle

How would I go about making a javascript for a button to select and deselect all checkboxes?

Checkbox HTML (they all look the same with a different value):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="moviebox[]" value="Zombieland" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;">
```

My button:

```
<input type="button" value="Select All/None">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add name="movieboxes" for all the checkboxes you want the button to affect.

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="movieboxes" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;"/> Zombieland<br/>
```

2. Add onClick for the button

```
<input type="button" onClick="toggleMovieBoxes()" value="Select All/None">
```

3. What the function basically does is get all the elements with the 'movieboxes' name and that loops everyone of them and flips his value (From true to false and from false to true)

Your entire html file should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function toggleMovieBoxes(){
            var movie_cbs = document.getElementsByName('movieboxes');
            for (var i=0, n=movie_cbs.length;i<n;i++) {
                movie_cbs[i].checked = !movie_cbs[i].checked;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="checkbox"  name="movieboxes" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;"/> Zombieland<br/>
<input type="checkbox"  name="movieboxes" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;"/> Zombieland 2<br/>
<input type="button" onClick="toggleMovieBoxes()" value="Select All/None">
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:**

Added a variable so all the checkboxes will be synced according to its value, also added a tiny touch so the user know better that this is a toggle button and it does something different everytime.

```
var is_checked = false;
function toggleMovieBoxes(){
            var movie_cbs = document.getElementsByName('movieboxes');
            var button = document.getElementById('btn');

            is_checked = !is_checked;

            if(is_checked)
                 button.value = "Deselect all";
            else
     button.value = "Select all";

            for (var i=0, n=movie_cbs.length;i<n;i++) {
                movie_cbs[i].checked = is_checked;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I notice when I have checkboxes selected before pressing the button, these will become unselected when the button is pressed and selected once again after the button is pressed another time to deselect all. Would you know if there is a solution for that, where all checkboxes become synced regardless of which are preselected?

Comment: Thank you! This is great

Answer (score 1):

Add a [click event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your button and then toggle all the checkboxes when it's clicked.

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".select-all");
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
let everythingChecked;

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = everythingChecked ? false : true;
  });
  everythingChecked = !everythingChecked
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="foo">
<input type="checkbox" name="bar">
<input type="checkbox" name="baz">

<button type="button" class="select-all">
  Button
</button>
```